# How to parse the string using sscanf() from regular expression?

Tags: c++, regex, linux, scanf

Following is my string

```
const char* str = "./a.out(__gxx_personality_v0+0x35d) [0x400e5d]";
```

I want to get only "0x400e5d" string i.e. the sub string enclosed in the [ and ] brackets.

I tried following but could not worked:

```
 char temp[1024];
 sscanf(symbol, "%*[^[]%1023[^]]", temp);
```

But it gives "[0x400e5d" output. How to avoid "[" in the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the `[`:

```
sscanf(symbol, "%*[^[][%1023[^]]", temp);
```

Note the extra `[` which represents itself.